# Disable git clean filter for checkout and stash pop

Tags: git, git-filter

We use the auto-format tool [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) on our git repositories, they run in a [git clean filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_b).

The problem is that users sometimes turn off their filters (don't ask). This leads to some bad formatting in some commits. Checking out these commits, while having the clean filter active, shows the bad formatting as diffs.

The filter is applied on `git diff` and others, and now users can't checkout another commit (warning about losing changes), so they turn off their filter, and create more problems since it's easy to forget to turn it on again.

One solution is to apply the auto-format on the server repository, I'm looking into it.
I like seeing the auto-formatting on `git diff`, so I see what I'm going to commit.

The question is: can we prevent running the clean filter on given operations, such as `checkout`, `stash pop`, and such?

Any better suggestion?

Comment: One workaround is to specify an invalid or dummy clean filter on `checkout`, like `git -c filter.foo.clean=bar checkout`.

Comment: Best dummy filter is `cat`, that works even for "required" filters.

Answer (score 2):

First, a note: `git checkout` should not run the clean filter at all, because it only does an index → work-tree copy.<sup>1</sup>  This runs the *smudge* filter instead.  Only index ← work-tree copy operations use the clean filter.

Since `git stash save` / `git stash push` does an index ← work-tree operation, it will use the clean filter.

Stash's `apply` and `pop` invoke `git merge-recursive`, which is more complicated.  While some merging happens in the index, this sometimes needs to do smudging and/or cleaning,<sup>2</sup> so you will see some cases of clean filter invocation here too.

As ElpieKay suggested in the comment, a quick and dirty, but easy, way to disable a filter is to temporarily override its driver's configuration on the command line, with the front-end's `-c` option: `git -c filter.name.type=noop` for each applicable *`name`* (driver name in `.gitattributes`) and *`type`* (`clean` or `smudge`).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is true whether `git checkout` is doing a branch-switch (`git switch` operation in Git 2.23 or later) or a file-restore (`git restore` operation in Git 2.23 or later).  In either case, checkout updates index copies of some file(s) if/as appropriate, then updates the work-tree copy from each updated or selected index copy.

That is, when using `git checkout -- paths`, the given *`paths`* get updated in the work-tree, from the copies already present in the index: this requires smudging.  When using `git checkout tree-ish -- paths`, the given *`paths`* get copied from the given *`tree-ish`* into the index and then copied to the work-tree: this also requires smudging.

Or, when using `git checkout commit`  or `git checkout branch`, the index entries that are different between the previous `HEAD` and the newly selected one are updated in the index, then copied to the work-tree, which requires smudging.

<sup>2</sup>`git merge -X renormalize` always runs both, doing a smudge first and then a clean, before merging, for every file in every commit, using the `.gitattributes` from the work-tree.  Setting `merge.renormalize` in your configuration has the same effect, unless you override this with `git merge -X no-renormalize`.  While `git merge-recursive` is lower level than `git merge`, I expect it does pretty similar things for the two commits that aren't represented by existing work-tree contents.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I have something going on, the clean filter seems to run on more occasions than you mean that it should. See here a minimal example https://gist.github.com/fleutot/f7b0f0c21b9819c95ad833859691985e .  I wonder if the part of my prompt that print git status is at fault.

Comment: Interesting. What Git commands do you have your shell run before printing a prompt?

Comment: It seems this comes from https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh `__git_ps1`, which gives not one but two runs, with my example gist above.

Comment: There is a lot of code in there. The command I suspect most is `git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet || w="*"`: to do a diff Git will sometimes need to clean the work-tree copy so as to compare the result of cleaning to the index copy. Normally Git tries to use information saved in the index to avoid this step, but perhaps that's not working. Why it would do this *twice* per prompt is not clear: there's a second `git diff` but it specifically calls for `--cached` which only needs to use the HEAD and index copies, with no call for running the clean filter.

Comment: It appears the `git diff` operations on row 508 and 509 of  github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh are what makes the clean filter run. I've added the `-c filter.*.clean=""` to these two commands, and the filter doesn't run on prompt anymore.

Comment: We came to the same conclusion, and confirmed, that's working! I'll write an answer here, I wonder if this would be something to send to the mailing list. As for the second call, until I have found why I'd let it be on me and my .bashrc.

Comment: One other question comes to mind: are you using per-file-invocation, old-style filters, or the new (not all that new any more) long-running filter setup? Old-style filters run once per *file* (vs one invocation per `git` run for long-running filters).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210509/discussion-between-gauthier-and-torek).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I got a little over-enthusiastic. The answer below solves the filter running on every prompt, but not the filter introducing (actually not even real) changes to local files, thus preventing `checkout`.

---

The `__git_ps1` function provided in git's `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh` runs `git diff`, which in turn runs the relevant clean filters.

Although I'm not sure about all the steps involved in the undesired behavior, it seems that the changes created by the clean filter (probably triggered by the prompt) hindered `checkout` and `stash pop`, in order to protect from possible loss of uncommitted work.

A solution is to disable clean filters in the `git diff` operations of `git-prompt.sh`, using the trick from @ElpieKay. In [this version of git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d04ce75c4dd4bf0aeda7383c4d791daa049c98a/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), it's on row 508 and 509.

```
- git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet || w="*"
- git diff --no-ext-diff --cached --quiet || i="+"
+ git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet -c filter.*.clean=""  || w="*"
+ git diff --no-ext-diff --cached --quiet  -c filter.*.clean="" || i="+"
```