# How to bypass a git clean filter when adding and committing

Tags: git

I have a filter set up to clean certain pieces of metadata and output from a Jupyter Notebook in a git repository. I came across a situation where I wanted to temporarily bypass the filter for a single stage -> commit sequence, and I am wondering if there there is a way to do this more generally (maybe an option in `git add` or `git commit` that bypasses the filter?)

I am looking for either a simple way to do this or an explanation of why it is not possible.

Here is what I have considered so far:

- `git add --renormalize`... does the opposite of what I want to do
- [Disable git clean filter for checkout and stash pop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60869862/21891079): this question discusses how the clean filter relates to `checkout` and other git commands, but not the `add` to `commit` workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the clean and smudge commands of a filter driver are specified in configuration files, we can pass temporary values to the variables to overwrite values from configuration files with the help of [-c <name>=<value>](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).

```
git -c filter.<driver>.clean=foo add
git -c filter.<driver>.clean=foo commit
```

`foo` could be empty or maybe `cat`, so that the file content is unchanged. If you have multiple drivers, use multiple temporary values to disable them all.